# use different JDKs for different Jenkins builds, without slaves

Tags: java, jenkins, java-11

Looking for a way to build some projects with Java 8 and some with Java 11 on the same Jenkins server with no slaves. I added the JDKs to the global tools (Java 11 is a tarball, no installer) and selected the JDK in a project configuration. When I build, it extracts the JDK fine to the Jenkins tools directory as expected.

The problem is that JAVA_HOME is not set so the Maven build fails.

I do not want to set JAVA_HOME globally since it needs to change based on the JDK being used to build each project. I also don’t want to set in the project themselves since they shouldn’t care where the JDK is installed.

Is there any way to set JAVA_HOME based on JDK selected?

Does Jenkins expect the JDK to be completely installed (added to system path) or is extracting it enough? I would think that having to install to the system path would mean we would be required to use slaves.

We are using RHEL x64 v7.6.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the jenkinsfile or declarative pipeline? If so, then just add JAVA_HOME

Example:

```
node('master') {
    env.JAVA_HOME="${tool 'jdk-8u45'}"
    env.PATH="${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin:${env.PATH}"
    sh 'java -version'
}
```

See this link: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/204421664-Select-which-Java-JDK-to-use-in-Pipeline

Comment: WorkflowScript: 24: Too many arguments for map key "node" @ line 24, column 9.
           node('master'){
           ^

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the top-level directory Java tarball was "jdk-11.0.1+13". I needed to add this to the tool "Subdirectory of extracted archive" field on the global tools configuration plug-in. After doing this, the PATH and JAVA_HOME were set by Jenkins to the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what user @dalmo-santos said

The `tool` must be preconfigured in Jenkins

`Manage Jenkins → Global Tool Configuration.`

So the config would be

```
node('devbuild-01') {
  env.JAVA_HOME="${tool 'JDK13'}" //JDK13 is pre-configured in Jenkins
  env.PATH="${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin:${env.PATH}"
  sh 'java -version'
}
```